# gcloud + PHP Cron-Job

Tags: php, cron, gcloud

I´d like to create a cronjob in the gcloud - but i get the following error:

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

Here is my code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

require "../simple_html_dom.php";
require "../functions.php";
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$output = array();
scrap_info($url);

if(count($output) > 0){
   $db = new FirestoreClient();
   $collection = $db->collection('standings');
   foreach ($output as $value) {
      $collection->set([
         'place' => $value[0],
         'team' => $value[1],           
         'points' => $value[8]
      ]);
   }
}
```

How can I get that script running?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have successfully deployed a cron job  and the error is returned when corn is sending a request to the service that runs the code you shared?